# How to use SetTimer replace Sleep()?

Tags: c++, winapi, sleep

I have a application that needs do something step by step, serially, like this:

```
...
func1();
Sleep(2000);
func2();
Sleep(3000);
func3();
...
```

As we know, calling Sleep() will cause the user interface to "freeze", so for example there is no response when trying to move the application window.

So, I tried using SetTimer() instead, as it seems that it would not cause the UI to freeze, but my question is how can I implement the same "waiting" function as Sleep() when using SetTimer()?

```
...
func1();
SetTimer(hwnd, ID_Timer2s,2000, Timerfunc2s);// how to make sure 2seconds waiting happen between func1 and func2?
func2();
SetTimer(hwnd, ID_Timer3s,3000, Timerfunc3s);
func3();
...

// my intention is kill the timer once timeout, then go back next func2(), how?
VOID CALLBACK Timerfunc2s( 
    HWND hwnd,        
    UINT message,
    UINT idTimer,
    DWORD dwTime)
{ 
    KillTimer(hwnd, ID_Timer2s);
} 

VOID CALLBACK Timerfunc3s( 
    HWND hwnd,        
    UINT message,
    UINT idTimer,
    DWORD dwTime)
{ 
    KillTimer(hwnd, ID_Timer3s);
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Thats not how `SetTimer` works. If you want to do something like that, either create a thread, or do the work in your timer callbacks.

Comment: Yeah, this is all backwards. Move the code to a thread and keep the sleep. Well, really the sleep looks wrong. Better will be to wait until you are ready to proceed, rather than sleep for arbitrary periods of time.

Comment: With `SetTimer` you can start receiving `WM_TIMER` messages at specific time period (e.g. 300ms, or 5sec). You can handle it and do what necessary.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Moving the work to a background thread won't work if `func2()` and `func3()` must be called from the UI thread (say, because they display UI).

Comment: @RaymondChen Generally you'd then send a message to a main thread window, or similar, to get the code executed on that thread. But the resulting code is far easier to read done that way.

Comment: @theB, thanks, can you demo base on my sample code?

Comment: @RaymondChen's answer is what I meant by "or do the work in your timer callbacks" As far as creating a thread (assuming that `func1()` et al don't need to be on the UI thread) look at the documentation for [`CreateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx) and the example it links [Creating Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516.aspx)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, exactly, in func2&func3, I need to update something on UI.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether the code you posted is running in the context of a window procedure, e.g., as the result of the user selecting a menu item?  If so, my answer doesn't apply, and I'll delete it.

Comment: Move your work to a separate thread, particularly if you really do have 45 steps as you say it will be by far the simplest solution.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, do you mean I should put all the 45 functions into a thread? then it would be ok for UI update. For the 45 steps example, I just  want let you understand more easier. Actually, the must-have 45 functions  are different, they are for different functions and aims.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, please keep your answer there, do not delete it. my program need to update every function execution result/progress to GUI.So, I don't want the GUI freeze during the running. thanks.

Comment: You sound like you'd happiest with my suggested approach, but from what you've said about your application so far it doesn't sound like a good fit.  If I understand rightly, your application gives the user a bunch of options, and once they've chosen one of those options it goes off and does what they've asked, which takes a considerable amount of time.  Have you considered having the main program launch a child program to do the actual work?  The child program could then present its own window (using the approach shown in my answer) to give the user feedback as to what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) 3 options to do what you want. The first, using timers, Raymond Chen covered. The second, using a customized wait function, Harry Johnston covered. The third option is to create a thread, and do the work using that thread.

For example:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
{
    func1();
    Sleep(2000);
    func2();
    Sleep(3000);
    func3();
    ...
    return 0;
}

...

DWORD threadId = 0;
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 255, &ThreadProc, NULL, 0, &threadId);
```

The trouble comes when you need to interact with the UI. You can't directly do things to the UI from the alternate thread, but one technique you can use is to [post messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) to your UI and/or use shared state variables to affect the behavior of your UI thread.

Of course, it also should go without saying that as soon as you introduce threading, you also introduce the potential for hard to diagnose bugs, like race conditions and deadlocks. If `func1`, `func2` or `funcN` modify global state you will need to synchronize access, either through critical sections, or some other synchronization method.

Comment: why I choose this option is because minor change on my code, others also good, I will try it later, thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

You want to run `func2()` only after `ID_Timer2s` expires, so run it when `ID_Timer2s` expires. Don't run it immediately.

```
...
func1();
SetTimer(hwnd, ID_Timer2s,2000, Timerfunc2s);
...

VOID CALLBACK Timerfunc2s( 
    HWND hwnd,        
    UINT message,
    UINT idTimer,
    DWORD dwTime)
{ 
    KillTimer(hwnd, ID_Timer2s);
    func2();
    SetTimer(hwnd, ID_Timer3s,3000, Timerfunc3s);
} 

VOID CALLBACK Timerfunc3s( 
    HWND hwnd,        
    UINT message,
    UINT idTimer,
    DWORD dwTime)
{ 
    KillTimer(hwnd, ID_Timer3s);
    func3();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but seems the structure is strange and complicated. If I do like your ideas, then the functions will jump in timers, right?

Comment: It's strange and complicated because your execution flow is strange and complicated. You don't want to do everything at once; you want to do it in pieces, and you want to release control between each piece. So you schedule when you want the next piece to happen, and then you release control. When it's time to do step 2, you do it, and then you schedule step 3. And so on. That's what happens when your desired execution is nonlinear. Now, future language features may make this code easier to write, but you are inherently breaking your work in pieces and scheduling them.

Comment: sorry for my terrible structure. The reason I using this stupid structure is decided by hardware device, as the hardware cannot do all things once.So, I need do them all one by one. For the sleep(), it's for waiting device reboot. And, in my program, there is more than 45 times sleep(). sounds not good.

Comment: Since your program is a GUI program, it is already based on an event-driven state machine. (When the user clicks this button do that. When the user presses this key, do that. When this message arrives, do that.) This is just adding new events (timer events) to your states.

Comment: Yes, my program is a GUI application. Unfortunately, the user only need to click one button one time to do all steps, like I said before, func1(); func2(); func3();....funcN(); all the functions should be performed one by one. I just don't want the GUI freeze when running the program. Strange structure? maybe yes. But the requirement and hardware is just over there. thanks again for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, this is not usually an appropriate design for a GUI application.

However, it *can* be appropriate for some very simple applications, e.g., those that perform a task that requires no user interaction, with a GUI that does nothing but provide feedback as to the progress of the task.

In such cases, *and assuming that the code is not being called in the context of a window procedure*, something like this should work:

```
...
func1();
MySleep(hwnd, 2000);
func2();
MySleep(hwnd, 3000);
func3();
...

BOOL MySleepTimerFlag;

void MySleep(HWND hwnd, DWORD timeout)
{
   MySleepTimerFlag = FALSE;
   SetTimer(hwnd, ID_MySleepTimer, timeout, MySleepTimerFunc);
   while (MySleepTimerFlag == FALSE)
   {
      if (!GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) fail();
      TranslateMessage(&Msg);
      DispatchMessage(&Msg);
   }
}

VOID CALLBACK MySleepTimerFunc( 
    HWND hwnd,        
    UINT message,
    UINT idTimer,
    DWORD dwTime)
{ 
    MySleepTimerFlag = TRUE;
    KillTimer(hwnd, ID_MySleepTimer);
}
```

Note that this code was written off the cuff; I haven't attempted to compile it, never mind test it.  But it should at least give you the idea.

Also, note that you *can* eliminate the global if it upsets you - attach a pointer as a window property or suchlike - but again, globals aren't really all that bad when used in very simple applications. :-)

Finally, the proviso that the call to MySleep() must not be in the context of a window procedure is *important*.  That means that the first part of the code above must not, for example, be triggered by selecting a menu item.  If it is, then you *must* use the approach outlined in Raymond's answer instead, or create a new thread as David suggested.

... also, as Raymond pointed out, you have to be careful that the GUI doesn't have any modal elements such as menus or dialog boxes, or at least that they are disabled while this code is running.

Comment: Note that if the user tries to do something with your app during `MySleep` (like say open a menu or *gasp* try to exit the app), then strange things will happen.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I think you're assuming that the call is being made in the context of a window procedure?  If that's the case, then this approach would definitely be unwise.  I was assuming that the program performs the task in question unconditionally.  (I've edited my answer to make that explicit.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, thanks for your ideas, indeed it may be the hints to my problem. I will try it later with your code.

Comment: Even if outside a window procedure, the GetMessage call can enter a modal loop (e.g. if the message handler opens a dialog box or a menu) and then the code will not notice that MySleepTimerFlag is set until the modal loop exits.

Comment: @RaymondChen: thanks; I wasn't aware that menus were modal.  I thought the dialog box thing was kind of obvious, but I'll add another proviso.